# Método .load() creación de tabla <tbody> HTML y JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, html-tabla

Buen dia a todos,

El día de hoy necesito de su ayuda, estoy creando una tabla en HTML que se alimenta dinamicamente a travez de AJAX en este caso uso .load() ya que esta tabla tiene que actualizar en tiempo real los ADD o los DELETES que suceden en estos registros, el html, mi servicio web corren bien. Mi problema viene cuando a la hora que llega el callback del método .load() me imprime mi response dentro del cuerpo del tBody y después ya inserta las etiquetas .

**OTRA COSA** dentro de mis  genero los botones editar y borrar, con $.ajax dejan de funcionar, entiendo que es por temas del DOM , por lo que uso el método .on() el detalle es que cuando actualizo varias veces dejan de funcionar mis eventos 'click'

Si uso $.ajax mi tabla no se actualizaría y tendría que borrar y agregar con jquery cada cambio de registro y eso es una gran carga para el DOM.

Por favor su ayuda o alguna manera alterna de poderlo hacer.

Comparto mi código HTML , JS, y el RESPONSE en formato JSON

Agradezco de su tiempo

HTML TABLA

```
       <div class="tableUser">
                <table border="1" id="table-user">
                    <caption>Usuarios</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id User</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Apellidos</th>
                            <th>eMail</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>CURP</th>
                            <th>Posicion</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="data-user">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Mi código JQUERY

```
function tableUser() {
var urlsw = "MI URL SW";
var form = $('#config-user').attr('name')
var jnRequest = {
    action: "query",
    idUser: document.querySelector('#idUser').value,
    form: form
}
    $('#data-user').load(urlsw, jnRequest, function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {          
        if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
          var  result = JSON.parse(result)
            if ($.isEmptyObject(result.response)) {
                alert('no hay datos');
            } else {
                $.each(result.response, function (idx, opt) {
                    $('#data-user').append('<tr><td>' + opt.idUser + '</td><td>' + opt.name + '</td><td>' + opt.lastNameF + '</td><td>' + opt.lastNameM + '</td><td>' + opt.mail + '</td><td>' + opt.tel + '</td><td>' + opt.curp + '</td><td>' + opt.position + '</td><td><div><input id=edit type=button value=Editar  ><input id=delete type=button value=Borrar ></div></td></tr>')
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log('fallo la conexion')
        }
   });
```

Esto es lo queme imprime en el DOM

[image: me pone todo dentro de la etiqueta tbody todo lo demas lo hace bien y hasta aqui lo botones dentro de la tabla funcionan]

me pone todo dentro de la etiqueta tbody todo lo demas lo hace bien y hasta aqui lo botones dentro de la tabla funcionan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el método `load` de jquery es para cargar archivos que no son `json` e insertarlos en el selector especificado. Este método ss usa para cargar html, txt en el DOM. Si quieres cargar datos json deberías usar `get` o `getJSON`

Comment: Gracias! ya me quedo claro, y ahora trabajo solo con Ajax para peticiones al servidor y con LOAD para cargar texto o html.